# Which Data Control to use?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, webforms

I need to be able to view data from a SQL database, and select specific rows to print (dealing with this later).
Considering I don't need to edit the data at any point, and all I need is the data with one checkbox extra, what control would be best?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely a [GridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
<asp:SqlDataSource id="CustomersSource"
  SelectCommand="SELECT CustomerID, CompanyName, FirstName, LastName FROM SalesLT.Customer"
  ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:AWLTConnectionString %>" 
  runat="server"/>

<asp:GridView id="CustomersGridView" 
  DataSourceID="CustomersSource" 
  AutoGenerateColumns="False"
  EmptyDataText="No data available." 
  AllowPaging="True" 
  runat="server" DataKeyNames="CustomerID">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CustomerID" HeaderText="CustomerID" 
            InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="CustomerID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CompanyName" HeaderText="CompanyName" 
            SortExpression="CompanyName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName" 
            SortExpression="FirstName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName" 
            SortExpression="LastName" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```